# dropdown selectedindexchanged issue within modalpopup extender

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

I'm having a `dropdown` in a `ModalPopupExtender`. The `dropdown` values are updated dynamically.

The problem is While clicking on the button in modal popup...The `dropdown` values was refreshed. So I tried to take the selected value of `dropdown` within the `sectedindexchanged` event. But If I put breakpoint with this also the control is not coming.

Can anyone tell me the fix for this?

Comment: can you show your code..?

Comment: this may help http://forums.asp.net/t/1905741.aspx/1 setting the id.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedIndexChanged` is event triggered when the selection is changed, not when you change the items in the `dropDown`. for that you may use `DataSourceChanged` if you change the `dataSource` property or other, or other events, depend on what your code do ( please share it).

Comment: I wanted to have the selected values only.. So only I preferred SelectedIndexChanged.. But what happens is if I change the selection then automatically the dropdown gets refreshed and retains the old value

Comment: @SubbuMani you can save the selectedValue in a member, and when the dropDown refresh retrieve it... if i'm getting where you're going to

Comment: Yes that only am doing within in SelectedIndexChanged. But the control is not coming over there. Before that the values is restored. :(

Comment: so, if i understand you, you are storing the item when it changes, but you don't know when the dropDown is refreshed so you could use it

Comment: @SubbuMani have you tried hooking DataBinding and  TextChanged events?